# Sending and Receiving files in chunks with Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets, file-transfer, chunks, python-3.9

I'm trying to send and receive a file over a Python 3.9 socket but my code is only working half the time.

**The code for the client (file reader):**

```
import socket

r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
r.connect((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
with open("fileToRead.jpg", "rb") as fileReader:
    for data in fileReader:
        r.send(data)
    r.send("flag".encode())
print("I have finished reading")
userInp = ""
while userInp != "exit":
    userInp = input("Enter input: ")
r.close()
```

**The code for the server(file writer):**

```
import socket
w = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
w.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
w.listen(1)
conn, addr = w.accept()
print("Connection made from ", addr)

with open("fileToWrite.jpg", "wb") as fileWriter:
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data.decode() == "flag":
            break
        fileWriter.write(data)
        print("just wrote data")
    print("I have finished writing")
while True:
    input("Test to see if I can work after file transfer: ")
```

I need both the client and the server to still be connected after the file is transferred. The code I provided is only working half of the time for me and I don't know why. The half when it's not working, the server gets stuck on the line *print("just wrote data")*

Comment: TCP is a *stream protocol* - there is no guaranteed connection between the chunks of data you pass to `.send()` at one end, and the chunks you get via `.recv()` at the other.  So it would only be pure chance if you happened to receive "flag" as the entire contents of a chunk; it's more likely to be appended to the last chunk of the file data.  (It could even be split between two chunks!).  Your whole approach is unworkable, anyway, because "flag" could appear as four consecutive bytes of data from the file - you'd have no way to distinguish that from the actual EOF indication.

Comment: @jasonharper That makes a ton of sense actually, thank you so much for the quick response!!!